# Applying css media=print not working with MasterPages after pagebreaks

Tags: asp.net, html, css, master-pages

I´m using a css media=print file in a Page that is using a MasterPage.
I put some  pagebreaks like this in certain parts of the html code:

`<h1 style="page-break-before: always; height: 0px; line-height: 0px;">`

This works perfectly in the first page, meaning that the styles are applied correctly, but after the pagebreaks, the css is not working any more.

Looking somewhere, the advice was to delete the masterpage, and yeah, it worked, but it is not the best thing to do, ´cause I have to remember changing this page if the masterpage changes.

Anyone knows another way to solve this problem using MasterPages?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the H1 style to your CSS file.